# receive email via sendgrid in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, dns, sendgrid

I have a project where user could enter their name, email, and message they want to send.how can I use sendgrid to receive message from the users. let say user is eri@tekieonline.com and want to send message to eri@gmail.com. The "domain authentication" in my sendgrid account is different to @tekieonline.com it is like @frtuonline.com. I search through different article but all I get is sending email from the authenticated domain to my gmail.Now how can a user send email from any domain to my gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

From Sendgrid, you can send emails from your authenticated domain to any valid address you wish. I assume this is a contact form kinda situation. In which case, usually the email is sent from your authenticated domain to your inbox (Gmail in this case), and not from the user's email, because you're not authorized to send email as someone else's address/domain.
You can use something like `no-reply@yourowndomain.com` to send the email to your Gmail with user's name, email, and message. That's the usual practice :)

Comment: Thanks sykez I am trying like when user emails with gmail account from my app to my gmail and respond to it. How can I accomplish such thing.

Comment: @ErmiasKidanegebre You could use their [Inbound Email Parse Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Parse_Webhook/inbound_email.html) for receiving the email, and then sending your reply to the user through Sendgrid. Of cause this won't be like using an email client like Outlook or Gmail since you'll need to achieve this through your application itself (you've to develop this). Hope this helps :)